# WinForms - Make a Property Bindable in Data Sources Explorer

Tags: winforms, binding, datasource, design-time

I have a couple of ViewModel classes I have written for my WinForms application.  One is a parent view model, the other is a child view model.

```
public class EditDrawingViewModel : SecureEntityViewModel
{
    public DrawingChildViewModel ChildViewModel { get; private set; }

}
```

In my form I have dropped a BindingSource in the Designer, and set its DataSource property to a new Project Data Source of type EditDrawingViewModel.

I want to set a binding to something else to the DrawingChildViewModel property of the main view model.

So say a new BindingSource named DrawingVMBindingSource.  I want to set it's DataSource to EditDrawingViewModel.ChildViewModel.  However, the property does not show in the Data Source explorer - I only get List implementations.

[image: designer]

So in the above, Materials, DrawingAreas, DrawingApplications are lists.  Nothing else shows up.  I would like to see ChildViewModel but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

To create the object data source:

1. Build your project.

Note:
You must build the project before objects in the project can be selected in the Data Source Configuration Wizard.

2. Click Add New Data Source in the Data Sources window.

The Data Source Configuration Wizard starts.

3. On the Choose a Data Source Type page, select Object, and then click Next.
4. On the Select the Data Objects page, expand the namespace nodes and select the check box next to the class you want to create the datasource from.
5. Click Finish.

The chosen object appears in the Data Sources window.

Comment: Is there no way to browse to the property to set the binding?  I know I can add the child view model separately and wire up data source in code, but I just wanted to set the binding to the property in the designer.

Comment: When you created your childview datasource, you can set the datasource and datamember on the control you want bind to. The datamember is used for the property you want to bind to.